# How to use a trait as a route controller method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
Target [App\Http\Controllers\Traits\FileUploadTrait] is not instantiable.
```

I get this error when trying to send a file upload to this route:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Traits;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

trait FileUploadTrait
{

    /**
     * File upload trait used in controllers to upload files
     */
    public function saveFiles(Request $request)
    {
      //some file upload code
    }

}
```

in my route:

```
Route::post('upload/files', ['uses' => 'Traits\FileUploadTrait@saveFiles', 'as' => 'media.upload']);
```

how to use a trait as a route controller@method?

Comment: You simply __cannot__. Create a separate class and `use` it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a Trait as controller since Trait's are not classes, but actually they   "are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP." [(See php docs)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

A trait is not instantiable, this means that under the hood, Laravel can't do
`$controller = new FileUploadTrait()` to use it.

To use a trait, you must include it on some class, for example:

```
class MyController {
    use FileUploadTrait;
}
```

Then you define your routes to use that class that you define.

Answer (score 1):

traits arent callable... which means :) you cannot call them :Dlol, sorry - couldnt help myself... anyway try with something like this :)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class MahController extends Controller {
   use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\FileUploadTrait;
}
```

Traits cannot be 'instantiated', you add them on objects.